# Protein-Protein Simulation using Gromacs

Tags: docking, protein-protein-interaction, simulated-data

Can we do protein-protein simulation through Gromacs? if yes, can anyone teach me the correct procedure to get this done.

Thank you,

Comment: This is a very broad question. Could you kindly limit it to a specific technical issue? Secondly a reproducible example is always helpful. FYI the question has received a closed request.

Comment: I'd suggest looking at one of the many [tutorials](https://tutorials.gromacs.org/) on the subject